# Crash with typeface (null reference)

Tags: android, fonts, crash, typeface

As you can see on screens, my project crash when I launch an activity on AVD.
My project use properly fonts and "setTypeFont" on other layout, but this one don't work and I don't know why !
I try a lot of things but I'm really lost now !!
This problem appears since few days, after an gradle update on android studio.

Thank's for your help.

[JAVA code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Ced.jpg)

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhQtF.jpg)

[Fonts folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hmOY.jpg)

[Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1OxW.jpg)

[Crash log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSnGF.jpg)

Comment: try removing final keyword from your view in your fragment java code

Comment: Hi achprod! and welcome to stackoverflow. I just wanted to remind you that it may be easier for others to help you if you wrote the code in to your question instead of taking a picture of it.  ;)

Comment: Oups, sorry for the screens !
No change without "final" keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you haven't used R.id.titre1 somewhere else. Press Ctrl and hover your mouse over the id and check to which layout it is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

gradle has no problem. The main problem is where Android loses access to textView due to its rootview (View c) changed .
In fact, this error occurred because engine not found any text with id t1 .

1- Make sure the textview t1 is defined in fragment_a1

2- do like this :

```
private View v = null ;
private TextView t1 ;
private Typeface mtf1 ;
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (v == null){
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting_app_tab2, container, false);
            mtf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf");
            t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titre1):
            t1.setTypeface (mtf1) ;
        }

        return v;
    }
```

It's work for me , I hope work for you too .